# Pop up images in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter. there is image in my website when i clicke on the image then it pop up and show the bigger image but the pop up image is showing behind the navbar .

show in css i am making the z index of navbar 1 and pop up image z index 2 show my problem solved ..

but now problem is when i scroll down then my navbar goes behind the text and images(MY navbar is fixed).

here is my html code of pop up images

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h6>
        Lalco Residency offers you a host of world-class amenities that are guaranteed to make your stay a pleasurable experience.</h6>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amenities/amen_0002.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amenities/BADMINTON-COURT.jpg');?>"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a class="fancybox" title="Image 1" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amenities/amen_0012.jpg');?>"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/amenities/CONFERENCE-HALL-PARTY-HALL.jpg');?>"></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my navbar code

```
<div class="header-navi">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="has-submenu">
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url('rooms');?>">Rooms</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('amenities');?>">Amenities</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('services');?>">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: just increase pop up image z index not nav z index

Comment: then it goes to behind the nav bar

Comment: i think you have to try position attribute of navbar....

Comment: try with z index of navbar 9 and pop up image z index 99

Comment: please give some example the i can easily understand..kunal

Comment: images "z-index:9999999" should do

Comment: vinie when i make z index of navbar 9 and pop up image z index 99 ..then popup show properly but my navbar goes behind the images and text when i scroll down

Comment: try "position: fixed" for navbar

Comment: kunal i alredy did this

Comment: This I do not think has any thing really to do with codeigniter

Comment: This is css's z-index issue not the codeigniter, in that case you need to verify that the modal should have the relatively large z-index value to some kind of 99999999 and the navbar to some 9 to over-ride the navbar with your modal.

Comment: What do you want after popup navbar also visible?

Comment: after popup i want navbar hide